# reading and caching html fragment for use on django template

Tags: django

I need to grab four html fragments from an external web site and display them within my django site's header and footer. I definitely need to cache these for some period of time.

My initial thought was to use urllib2 to read the http and then write the html to files to my server. Implemented through a Django context processor, the code checks the timestamps of the four files and retrieves updated versions if necessary before reading them into template variables.

I appear to be maxing out Django's template variable size for one of the four files. This forced me to use readlines() and to pass that file into the template as an array.

Is there a more elegant way to retrieve four html fragments from an external site, cache them and pass them to my templates?

Here's what my base.html template looks like now:

```
{{ integration_prehead|safe }}
<head>
{{integration_head|safe }}
...
</head>
{% for l in integration_topper %}{{ l|safe }}{% endfor %}
{{ block content }}{{ endblock content }}
{{ integration_footer|safe }}
```

The prehead.html isn't much of anything other than the doctype and opening html tag. The head.html is a bunch of javascript and stylesheets. The topper.html and the footer.html are the biggest pieces and they're the top and bottom of the pages. The topper, in particular, can change every 15 minutes so it's not practical to hard-code it on my templates.

Topper is 39k and too big to read into a single Django template variable, hence the for loop.

Comment: Html fragment is not a part of your site. How could you cache external html with help of internal template system? Are you sure your question is correct? Give example please.

Comment: However it's interesting, +1.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question to provide some additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any control over the server you're pulling the fragments from, your best bet is to set up dedicated views that return just the fragments and not the entire HTML document.

You can then use Django views to either manually save the fragments to disk or use [Django's Cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs). The cache framework will be much more robust and provide additional means of storage such as via database or memcached, but it's not guaranteed to store the fragment for a defined period of time. For example, memcached will lose everything if the server has to be restarted.

If the source server is not in your control, I'd highly recommend that you run the document through an HTML parser first, and pull out and pass in to your template only the pieces that your need. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a nice one for python.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. The external server breaks the html document into four components. I've added some additional description to my question above. I like your idea about using Django views and Django's Cache framework. Are you suggesting four views that call the fragments and cache them? Since these are needed on every page of my site, how would these four views tie in?